# Getting path of images from the model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model

I'm working on a mapping application which uses a module called Gmaps4Rails.  Using this gem I define the path to images from within my model and can have it based on some data which image I'm using.
It's working fine in development environment but it breaks on production because it can't find the image folder.  This is how the code looks like inside the model:

```
  def gmaps4rails_marker_picture

    {
    "picture" => "/images/oilpumpjack.png",
    "width" => "32",
    "height" => "32"
    }
  end
```

Is there any easy way of getting the correct path from within the model (I don't want to hardcode it)?

Regards,
Johann

Comment: How are you accessing the image in the template? Is your asset directory somewhere else in production?

Comment: The asset directory is on same location (relative to the app) as on development.  I'm using a built in gem function to access the map:  =gmaps({"map_options" => { "zoom" => 6,"center_latitude" => 65, "center_longitude" => -19},"markers" => { "data" => @json }})

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Sprockets for serving images, try this:

```
def gmaps4rails_marker_picture    
    {
    "picture" => ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('oilpumpjack.png'),
    "width" => "32",
    "height" => "32"
    }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go, it might work:

change

```
"picture" => "/images/oilpumpjack.png"
```

to this

```
"picture" => "#{Rails.root}/public/images/oilpumpjack.png"
```

i was having a similar problem with another gem.hope it helps

**edit**

In config/environments/production.rb set

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Comment: I'm getting closer.  This creates the correct path but now I'm getting a route error:  Started GET "/var/app/public/images/oilpumpjack.png" for x.x.x.x at Sat Sep 10 20:52:56 +0000 2011

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/var/app/public/images/oilpumpjack.png"):

Comment: No, I'm using rails 3.0.  I have gone through the instructions and I'm doing the correct thing.  Thanks so much for your help, I will use the default markers until I have time to look closer at this.

Comment: Thanks Hishalv, I had already set the config.serve_static_assets to true but it has not effect (I restarted apache after the change earlier today).